# youtube embed how to hide recommended videos in apostrophe video

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to NOT show the recommended videos after the embedded video is done playing. I did see the option to add "rel=0" param in the URL but that does not work. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 easy steps:

- copy the **apostrophe-oembed** module to your own lib/modules/ directory from the **node_modules/apostrophe/lib/modules** directory. We do that to be able to customise the oembed module without altering the original module.
- edit the file **apostrophe-oembed/lib/youtube.js** at line 17 from `response.html = response.html.replace('feature=oembed', 'feature=oembed&wmode=opaque');`  to  `response.html = response.html.replace('feature=oembed', 'feature=oembed&wmode=opaque&rel=0');`
- restart your server to see it in effect with existing videos

Comment: We should break up enhanceOembetter into several methods, one per service, so that copying the whole thing is clearly not necessary and you can just override the one method in an implicit subclass. At the moment though, it is indeed a bit of a pain to avoid copying and pasting the module to make this change.